# Issue with VR Player movement passing through colliders

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I'm currently developing an application for Oculus2 that involves configuring the movement of the VR Player. I've encountered an issue with colliders in the scene, specifically walls. Here are the two scenarios I'm facing:

1. When the user opens the application and moves around towards the wall, everything works as expected. No issues here.
2. However, if the user opens the application and physically moves to their left, they are able to pass through the colliders and see the outside environment on the other side of the wall.

Can anyone provide suggestions on how to fix this issue? I want to prevent the user from passing through colliders when moving physically in the VR environment. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!